# Shadows in Java displaying incorrectly

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to create a class in Java which will add a simple box shadow to any given UI element. Normally, it displays correctly, however when it is applied to a button, the shadow gets darker each time the mouse enters or exits the button.

The paint function is as follows:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Rectangle bounds = g.getClipBounds();

    g.setClip(bounds.x + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) - (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod), bounds.y + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) - (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod),
            bounds.width + 2 * (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod), bounds.height + 2 * (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod));

    int red = UIConstants.SHADOW_COLOR.getRed();
    int green = UIConstants.SHADOW_COLOR.getGreen();
    int blue = UIConstants.SHADOW_COLOR.getBlue();
    int alpha = UIConstants.SHADOW_COLOR.getAlpha();

    for (int x = (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) - (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod); x < bounds.width + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) + (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod); x++)
    {
        for (int y = (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) - (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod); y < bounds.width + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod) + (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod); y++)
        {
            int dx = Math.abs(x - Math.max(Math.min(x, bounds.width + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod)), (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod)));
            int dy = Math.abs(y - Math.max(Math.min(y, bounds.height + (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod)), (SHADOW_OFFSET + shadowOffsetMod)));

            float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            dist /= (SHADOW_SIZE + shadowSizeMod);
            if (dist > 1)
                dist = 1;

            dist = 1 - dist;

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, ((float)alpha * dist) / 255));
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    g.setClip(bounds);

    super.paint(g);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `MouseListeners` or `MouseMotionListeners` on your component?

Comment: Yes, I have MouseListeners though disabling them does not solve the issue.

Comment: Only the button is getting repainted, so you are painting on the area around the button repeatedly, each time it gets a little darker, but is never reset to the original color. You'll probably have to tell the parent component to repaint/ update the region.

Answer (score 0):

> the shadow gets darker each time the mouse enters or exits the button.

Not sure exactly how your code is used. But (assuming you are usign Swing) this is a problem resulting from using a background color with transparency.

Swing components are either

1. opaque, in which case they guarantee to paint the background
2. non-opaque, in which case the parent component is used to paint the background.

In your case it sounds like the component is opaque, but the background is transparent so you break rule and you have painting issues.

Check out [Backgrouds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) fore more information and a couple of solutions:

1. make the component non-opaque and paint the background yourself
2. use a custom component as a wrapper to paint the background for you.